# What are the monodromy and saltation matrices of an ODE system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chaos-theory

Assume we have the following ODE system:

$$\mathbf{y}^{(n)} = \mathbf{F}\left(x,\mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}',\mathbf{y}'',\ldots, \mathbf{y}^{(n-1)} \right),$$

which is unfolded into:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1^{(n)} \\
y_2^{(n)} \\
\vdots \\
y_m^{(n)}
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
f_1 \left (x,\mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}',\mathbf{y}'',\ldots, \mathbf{y}^{(n-1)} \right ) \\
f_2 \left (x,\mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}',\mathbf{y}'',\ldots, \mathbf{y}^{(n-1)} \right ) \\
\vdots \\
f_m \left (x,\mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}',\mathbf{y}'',\ldots, \mathbf{y}^{(n-1)} \right)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

What are the definitions of monodromy and saltation matrices?